# Which laptop do you recommend, i5 5287u with iris 6100 or i5 6200 with nvidia 920m?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor

I want to buy a laptop but I have a limited budget. I will install Ubuntu on it, and I use it for transcoding purposes, such as video editing, blender, audio-video conversion, so I need a CPU with higher single core performance. Many people complains of AMD CPUs for their weaker performance. I am not a game fan except chess but I also want a decent GPU.
Intel i5 5287u and i5 5257u CPUs has iris 6100 GPUs on CPU chip so they don't have external GPU. I tried to compare iris 6100 vs nvidia 920m but some say iris 6100 is only par with  nvidia 840m, however it appears that  in the following links  iris 6100 is slightly better than even `nvidia gt 920m`.
[iris 6100 vs nvidia gt 920m](http://www.game-debate.com/gpu/index.php?gid=3163&gid2=2996&compare=geforce-920m-4gb-vs-iris-graphics-6100-mobile)

[iris 6100 vs nvidia gt 920m](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=3164&cmp%5B%5D=3192)

I am also interested in bitcoin mining.
Considering all of these which one would you recommend? You can also suggest your own models.

EDIT:

- bitcoin mining score for GeForce 920M is 39.92 mHash/s
- bitcoin mining score for Core i5 5257U is 54.21 mHash/s

Single core performance for i5 5287U  outgoes even many intel i7 processors.

Comment: Doesn't bitcoin mining make heavy use of the GPU?  I'd say the nVidia chip would be better than the Iris then, even for the video editing and other tasks you want to perform.  Best to make sure Linux drivers are good to go though too.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Thank you for responding. I found another option cheaper than the above options.  It has `intel  i3 5015 cpu` and `nvidia 920m` , it's `DELL 3558-B01F45C` . What do you think?

Comment: Personally I'd go with an i5 or i7.  For what you want to do, I'd suggest the i5 but maybe someone else has some insight on the i3 for those kinds of tasks.  I don't have anything to really base my opinion on, its just personal preference I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin mining will not be worth it (will not earn much, the earnings will not be enough to cover the electricity costs). The Nvidia Geforce 920M is a very weak card and the Iris 6100 is pretty strong for a integrated GPU, so they should be around the same performance (one may outperform another slightly because of optimizations). Both are not great for video rendering but they will suffice. It doesn't really matter which one you get if they are same specs. The amount of RAM is also a big factor as you want at least 8GB. Both of these cards will not render anything over 1080p well.

Comment: You appear to know the subject. I thought the same, you approved my verdict. By the way it's not `iris pro 6100`, it's `iris 6100`, though `pro` suggests higher in quality.  I need to decide between `Casper C5ı.5287-8T35t Intel Core İ5 5287U 2,9Ghz 8 Gb 1 Tb 15.6'' ` and `HP P0E76EA 15-ac111nt i7 5500-15.6''-8G-1TB-2G`  the latter has `AMD Radeon R5 M330` GPU

Comment: @kenn Sorry for the mistake, it is the iris 6100. The R5 M330 shares its VRAM with the system RAM, just like the 6100 bit the HP has an i7, which can make video editing slightly better.

Comment: Thank you for the info. HP is about 50$ expensive, do you think that it worths?

Comment: @kenn I would say so yes. Whats your budget? Maybe we can find a better computer for the same price.

Comment: I said maximum 600$ at first but I forgot to extract very high tax in my country. so I can afford a notebook around 500$.

Comment: @kenn then these two are probably your best bets.

Answer (score 0):

I can speak for the bitcoin mining aspect only:

You must be aware that it will not be profitable no matter what you do with the notebook. But I guess you want to do some bitcoin mining to understand the concept (which I generally endorse).

Buy the **cheaper** of both notebooks, then buy some USB ASIC Miner which are available for around $10 and give you performance of 330MH/s to 2.5 GH/s which is around 6 to 50 times faster than your i5 and takes a fraction of the power. Examples for these gadgets are USB BlockErupter (https://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/block-erupter-usb-beginners-guide/) which is the lowest end available. The high-end for a small USB stick is The Avalon Nano (https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1022764.0) with around 3.6GH/s and $55 price tag.

Still not profitable, but at least it is a plan.